# Custom variables on product details page in Magento

Tags: magento, google-analytics, magento-1.4

**UPDATE:**
Hopefully this is a better explanation of the problem:

I'm trying to pass on the product SKU on my product details page to Google Analytics using `_setCustomVar`.
I'm running on Magento 1.4.0.1 and my Analytics async code is inserted by the default GA module in the `<head>` section and it looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();

</script>
```

The custom variable I'm trying to add has this syntax:

```
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',1,'View Product','<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getSku(), 'sku') ?>',3]);
```

According to the Analytic documentation, in order for the custom variable to be recorded, the `_setCustomVar` must be called BEFORE the `_trackPageView`, 
but there's no support for this in the default GoogleAnalytics module. There are 2 issues to this problem:

1. How can I add my `_setCustomVar` function BEFORE the default tracking code?
2. How can I add my `_setCustomVar` function ONLY on product pages?

---

**Original post:**

I'm trying to store the SKU of the product being viewed by a visitor in a Analytics Custom Variable. The syntax for this is `_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',3,'View Product','SKU12345',2]);`.

Obviously this snippet of code should be added only to the product detail pages, and not to the list, cart, or checkout pages. So I've tried editing the `view.phtml` file in `app/design/frontend/default/my_package/template/catalog/product` by adding the following piece of code:

```
<script>
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',
    1,
    'View Product',
    '<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getSku(), 'sku') ?>', 
    3]);
</script>
```

The problem is that the I'm adding this custom variable AFTER the basic tracking code, which is added by default in the `<head>` section, so it doesn't get recorded in Analytics.

I tried to avoid altering the core files with the Analytics module in `app/code/core/Mage/GoogleAnalytics/Block/Ga.php`, but I think the solution may lay there.
How can I add the piece of code that sets the custom variable so that it appears within the basic tracking code BEFORE `_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);`?

This is my async code provided by Analytics:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();

</script>
```

Idea from [here](http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2012/08/28/20-ways-use-custom-variables/)

Note: I'm using Magento 1.4.0.1 and the Analytics Asynchronous Syntax

Comment: Are you manually adding Google Analytics code to your header/footer, or do you use the magento Google Api ... http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/magento_google_analytics.htm ?

Comment: I'm using the Magento core Analytics module like in the siteground link you posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to make it work by modifying the default GoogleAnalytics module:

In `app/code/core/Mage/GoogleAnalytics/Block` copy the `Ga.php` file, then navigate to `/www/app/code/local/Mage/GoogleAnalytics/Block` and paste it (create the necessary folders if they don't exist).

in the new `Ga.php`, in the `_toHtml()` function after testing if Analytics is activated from the Magento backend, test if the current page is a product details page:

```
$_product = Mage::registry('current_product');  
if($_product) {
        //output code with _setCustom var
    } else {
        //output normal tracking code
    }
```

The code with the custom variable set looks like this:

```
$this->addText('
<!-- BEGIN GOOGLE ANALYTICS CODE -->
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push([\'_setAccount\', \'UA-25272379-1\']);
_gaq.push([\'_setCustomVar\', 1, \'Product View\',\''.$_product->getSku().'\', 3]);
_gaq.push([\'_trackPageview\']);

(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement(\'script\'); ga.type = \'text/javascript\'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = (\'https:\' == document.location.protocol ? \'https://ssl\' : \'http://www\') + \'.google-analytics.com/ga.js\';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName(\'script\')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
</script>
<!-- END GOOGLE ANALYTICS CODE -->
');
```

Answer (score 2):

This is currently working on one of our magento site, If you are using the Magento Admin Google API then you could either (1) create a custom module to extend it or (2) make sure (when viewing source) the `<script>_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar...` javascript is below var _gaq = _gaq || []; code block

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];

    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxx-3']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
    _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', '1', 'awe2', '<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getSku(), 'sku') ?>', '1']);

    (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();

 //]]>
</script>
```

**To Create a custom module**

in app/code/local/MageIgniter/GoogleAnalytics/etc/config.xml

```
  <config>
    <modules>
        <MageIgniter_GoogleAnalytics>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </MageIgniter_GoogleAnalytics>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <googleanalytics>
                <rewrite>
                    <ga>MageIgniter_GoogleAnalytics_Block_Ga</ga>
                </rewrite>
            </googleanalytics>
        </blocks>
    </global>
  </config>
```

Create in /app/code/local/MageIgniter/GoogleAnalytics/Block/Ga.php

```
    class MageIgniter_GoogleAnalytics_Block_Ga extends Mage_GoogleAnalytics_Block_Ga
    {

        private $remId = NULL;
        private $conversionId = NULL;
        private $conversionLabel = NULL;


        public function getPageName()
        {
            return $this->_getData('page_name');
        }


        protected function _getPageTrackingCode($accountId)
        {
            $pageName   = trim($this->getPageName());
            $optPageURL = '';
            if ($pageName && preg_match('/^\/.*/i', $pageName)) {
                $optPageURL = ", '{$this->jsQuoteEscape($pageName)}'";
            }
            return "
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', '{$this->jsQuoteEscape($accountId)}']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview'{$optPageURL}]);
    " . $this->getProductSku();
        }

      ......

        public function getProductSku(){
            if($product = Mage::registry('current_product')){
               return sprintf("_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s']);",
                    1,
                    'Sku',
                    $product->getSku(),
                    1
                ) . "\n";
            }

            return '';
        }

     ........
 }
```

see /app/code/core/Mage/GoogleAnalytics/Block/Ga.php for more help

Comment: That's cool, but I have 2 questions: #1 how did you modify the GA tracking code to include the customVar? #2 Isn't this piece of code shown on EVERY page of your magento site, such as CMS pages, category pages, checkout, cart etc?

Comment: By creating a custom module that extend the GA... read my updated answer

Comment: ok, but isn't that setting the custom variable on ALL pages (including the non product detail ones)?

Comment: Don't you mean the `<config>` XML code should go in in `app/code/local/RWS/GoogleAnalytics/etc/config.xml`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18744/discussion-between-bogdan-and-r-s)

Answer (score 0):

If you use the asynchrnous insert code of Google analytics, no matter where you place this code, it will only be applied when page is finished loading.
So you can add your `_gaq.push()` after of before as long as they're inline in the HTML code (not asynchronous)

The asynchronous code looks like :

```
(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(ga);
})();
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using the Async Syntax, however I've added my `_gaq.push()` after the head snippet and it's not getting data to Analytics.

I've edited my question to include the async code I'm using.

Comment: Are you sure of all that's around ? _setAccount ? _setDomainName ? Are you watching Real Time panel in GA admin ? if you manually add the code BEFORE : does it work ?

Comment: Yes, it includes `_setAccount` (edited the question again). I haven't tried adding it before because I don't know how to do that.

Comment: disable output of GA module, and execute JS all by yourself (copy past the tags, reorder it, and execute) in the console of firebug (on firefox) for example

Comment: Noticed in the console that I'm getting a JS error `_gaq is not defined` if I add my `_gaq.push()` before the async code

Comment: you must be missing some init code, did you insert the `var _gaq = _gaq || [];` before any _gaq.push ?

Comment: Right, so it's working if I manually add the `_gaq.push` BEFORE the async snippet, but not AFTER. Any ideas?

Comment: carefull, when executing JS in console, the page is already loaded, so the asynchronous mechanics could be broke. Anywaysare you sure that your _gaq.push are NOT asynchronous (in magento)?  you must not put then in the (function(){}) asynchronous method