# Magento get field added to Google Analytics code

Tags: magento

I've added a field to the Google Analytics module. (so this question is a general one, in this case with the Analytics module)

Looks like this (system.xml)

```
<another_code translate="label">
    <label>Another code</label>
    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
    <fields>
        <active translate="label">
            <label>Enable</label>
            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
        </active>
        <account translate="label">
            <label>Account Id</label>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>20</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
        </account>
    </fields>
</another_code>
```

This works fine, get's added to the DB. But...

How do I get it in the frontend? What would be the next step if I want to get the `<label>Account Id</label>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To get 'Account Id' value from above example
>
> Mage::getStoreConfig('google/another_code/account')

It is never a good idea to make changes to core so you could create a custom module to extend google Analytics

in app/code/local/MageIgniter/GoogleAnalytics/etc/system.xml (copy system.xml from above)

```
<config>
    <sections>
        <google translate="label" module="googleanalytics">
            <label>Google API</label>
            <tab>sales</tab>
            ....
           <another_code translate="label">
```

in app/code/local/MageIgniter/GoogleAnalytics/etc/config.xml

```
  <config>
    <modules>
        <MageIgniter_GoogleAnalytics>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </MageIgniter_GoogleAnalytics>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <googleanalytics>
                <rewrite>
                    <ga>MageIgniter_GoogleAnalytics_Block_Ga</ga>
                </rewrite>
            </googleanalytics>
        </blocks>
    </global>
  </config>
```

Create in /app/code/local/MageIgniter/GoogleAnalytics/Block/Ga.php

```
class MageIgniter_GoogleAnalytics_Block_Ga extends Mage_GoogleAnalytics_Block_Ga
{

     function _getPageTrackingCode($accountId){
         // to get 'Account Id' value from above example
         Mage::getStoreConfig('google/another_code/account')
     } 

     ........
}
```

See /app/code/core/Mage/GoogleAnalytics/Block/Ga.php or [Custom variables on product details page in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13121578/1191288)  for more help

Comment: Thanks! this one helped me on multiple levels :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you mean you can't see your new option in the `System > Configuration` screen. You need to add an `another_code` node into the ACL node of the configuration (usually found in adminhtml.xml). Don't forget to clear your cache and logout / back in to reload the acl permissions. As @R.S says though, you should definitely consider creating a custom module if you are currently editing the core.